# Move to the next answer button doesn't work correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Navigation via "move to the next answer" button (right-top corner of the screen) doesn't always work correctly in questions like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/339911). The reason is answers are not completely loaded yet. So after some taps scrolling stops on the middle of the answer's body (not on the top of it).

- App Version: 1.6.1.2
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.1.1 (Build 14B100)

Answer (score 2):

This will be fixed in 1.6.6.1.

The original idea was that if you're on the last loaded answer and tap next, it would scroll you to the loading indicator and start loading the next page. You would then have to tap again when the load finished.

Now we start loading on the second to last answer.  This won't help too much if you're tapping down really fast, but for casual reading it should keep you from seeing the spinner or stopping at the first 40px of a answer.